# Blank screen issue

Tags: xbox-360

I started my Xbox 360 as usual. It wouldn't load, just showed no signal. We moved the xbox to another tv, turned it on, worked for about 1 minute. Then it went to a blank screen saying just HDMI in the corner. Shut off everything, tried again, same problem. Nothing works. Please help. What do I do?

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the channel. Get a new HDMI cord and go to a new HDMI channel. Or just get a new Xbox? I suggest starting with a new HDMI cord.